# CouchDB & tagged docs: howto get tags s.t. there are docs with that tag and another tag

Tags: join, tags, couchdb

I dont know how to solve my problem with means of CouchDB only and without computation of the client.

I have a database with documents that represent notes (type:"note") and tags (type:"tag"). A tag has a category (e.g. category:"todo" or category:"place"). There are also other categories of tags.

A note has a list of tags, given as a list of IDs of the desired tag documents.

Example:

```
{id:"1", type:"note", tags:[2,3,...],   text:"blablabla"}
{id:"2", type:"tag",  category:"todo",  what:"foo"}
{id:"3", type:"tag",  category:"place", description:"The leaning tower of Pisa"}
{id:"4", type:"note", tags:[5,...],     text:"blablabla"}
{id:"5", type:"tag",  category:"place", description:"Mount Everest"}
```

Note 1 has a todo, Note 5 does not. The list of todo tags is:
[2]

What I desire is a list of place-tags such that there are notes at those places that also have a todo tag in their list, i.e., "places with todos": [3].

I would like couchDB to do all the work and not bother the client with extracting that information. Unfortunately I could not find a solution by myself (I considered view, view collation, list functions).

But I guess it can be done... does any of you know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the pairs of tags for notes with map function:

```
function (doc) {
  if (!doc.type || !doc.tags || doc.type != "note") return;
  for (var i in doc.tags) {
    for (var j in doc.tags) {
      if (i != j) emit([doc.tags[i],doc.tags[j]], doc);
    }
  }
}
```

and query for `[tag1, tag2]`. The problem is that you decided to use non-meaningful IDs for tags, so you have to know both tags' ID apriori to make a query. It would be convenient to change the scheme to:

```
{_id: "12345", type:"note", tags:["todo","place",...], text:"blablabla"}
{_id: "todo",  type:"tag",  ...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your approach would generate quite a large view as there are a a few hundred, may be a few thousand, notes with up to 10 tags! It does not seem reasonable to me to generate this view just for the purpose of this simple query.

Comment: You are right about the meaningless document ids, the id "todo" is not an option though, since there are more than one todos.

Given better ids, for my query ("give me places with todos") i would have to do some kind of range query over tuples [tag1,tag2], which is not possible (from what I understood).